Why doesn't my OP Amp comparator work in LTSpice? (AD8665)
When V2 > V1, Vout should output approx. 5.3V. When V2 < V1, Vout should be approx. 0V. But this op amp seems to always output 5.3V regardless what V2 is. What could be going on here? Is this the wrong OP amp for the job or is there something weird about the spice model? This model is from the standard LTSpice library.


The AD8665 is an op-amp IC, not a comparator IC. If you want to make a comparator, use a comparator IC, not an op-amp IC. Using an op-amp as a comparator is like using a kitchen knife as a screwdriver: it kind of works, but it's far from ideal.
--
Having said that. The input voltage range of the AD8665 does not go beyond the positive supply. Therefore, it cannot be used to detect when the positive input goes above 5.3 V. You would need a comparator IC whose input voltage range exceeds the supply rails. There are some that can work below the negative rail, but I don't believe there are any that can work above the positive rail. Your best bet is to power the positive supply of the comparator to a higher voltage, such as 10 V.

The AD8665 with VCC = 5 V, VEE = 0 V power supply has a common mode input voltage range of -0.1 to +3 volts as given on page 3 of the data sheet. Thus, you are operating the opamp outside of the recommended input voltage range which means the part may misbehave. A simple solution is to use voltage dividers on each input as shown below. This brings the reference and input voltages within the common voltage operating range of the device (be it an opamp or comparator).
You may want to add hysteresis to prevent chattering about the threshold point.
Others have mentioned that a comparator is a better choice. Comparators have higher switching speed and less delay. Opamps are relatively slow as they come out of saturation which makes them a poor choice for many comparator applications.The AD8665, as shown in Figure 36 in the data sheet, takes approximately 3 us to come out of saturation. A slow comparator delay is on the order of about 100 times faster.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

To add a bit of information, one of the ways an op-amp misbehaves is phase reversal, (and which we are seeing here), which is where the outputs flips polarity

Use two voltage sources for the negative terminal and the rail. The negative terminal should be below the positive rail. If you look in the datasheet it shows that in their testing they put the input voltage range at -100mv to 3V Vcm input range for a 5V power rail.
Another thing is opamps don't work very well as comparators, it would be better to use a comparator.

Maybe a separate question but, what are good comparators made from if not op amps?

@BobaJFET Good comparators are usually made from high-purity silicon, not other op-amps. Yes, they look the same on the schematic, but they are fundamentally different devices and need to be treated as such.

Go to a supplier (analog) and look for comparators  https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/comparators.html

@VoltageSpike read my mind. i'm already on it!

@voltage spike So the datasheet for AD8665 specifies single supply operation. 5V to 16V. Doesn't this seem to suggest the opposite of your first point?

No, look at the Vcm, the input range is 2V below 5V


Why doesn't my OP Amp comparator work in LTSpice? (AD8665)

You have incorrectly wired the op-amp by connecting the inverting input to the positive supply rail pin. You need to put a separate 5 volt supply on this power pin.

I'm not sure that the fact that they're not separate has anything to do with it. Making them separate in the simulation didn't change anything. My schematic is definitely wired wrong as per the datasheet however.  I agree with the other responses that AD8665 is not meant to be used as a comparator.

It's still wrong @BobaJFET because the input cannot be sensibly used unless it's at least a volt or so below the power rail. Look up the data sheet and look for input voltage range.

I agree with you. That's why I just stated that it's still wired wrong as per the datasheet. But your answer implies that the problem is that the positive rail and the inverting input are not separate. I think you could could re-word that a little.
